# How does chroot's use of qemu for cross compile environments work?

Tags: linux, chroot, qemu

To be able to do cross compiling there's a trick where you copy a static qemu binary into your `<different-arch-root-to-be>/usr/bin` and when you chroot into that filesystem, which has non-native binaries, magically the binaries are executable by the host cpu, and `uname -a` and similar claim that you are on the target architecture. The net result is that you can get dead simple cross compiling.

I can imagine a way this might work, but it would require `chroot` to be `qemu` aware.

Is this the case? I can't seem to find any documentation as to how this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux has a mechanism that allows plug-ins to be registered so that the kernel calls an interpreter program when instructed to execute a file: [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc). Simplifying a bit, when an executable file is executed, the kernel reads the first few bytes and goes like this:

- Does it start with the four bytes `\x7fELF` followed by a valid-looking ELF header? If so, use the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) loader inside the kernel to load the program and execute it.
- Does it start with the two bytes `#!` ([shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)))? If so, read the first line, parse what's after the `#!` and execute that, passing the path to the executable as an argument.
- Does it start with one of the magic values registered through the binfmt_misc mechanism? If so, execute the registered interpreter.

To run foreign-architecture binaries via Qemu, magic values corresponding to an ELF header with each supported architecture are registered through the binfmt_misc mechanism. You can see what is supported by listing the directory `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` (which is a special filesystem representing the current set of registered binfmt_misc interpreters in the kernel). For example:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
flags: 
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

So if an executable `/somewhere/foo` starts with the specified magic bytes, if you run `/somewhere/foo arg1 arg2`, the kernel will call `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /somewhere/foo arg1 arg2`.

It is not necessary to use a chroot for this mechanism to work, the executable could be anywhere. A chroot is convenient in order for dynamic executables to work: dynamic executables contain an absolute path to their loader, so if you run e.g. an ARM excutable, it will expect a loader located in `/lib`. If the loader is in fact located in `/different-arch-root-to-be`, a chroot to that directory is necessary for the executable to find the loader.

Comment: I'm really glad I asked! That's really useful information apart from this specific case.