# unable to find an interpreter when running a Windows executable

Tags: wine

I uninstalled my wine, and installed a higher version of wine by compiling source.

However when I run an exe executable (whose path is in `$PATH`), it doesn't work as it used to:

```
$  PDFXCview.exe   

run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for /home/tim/program_files/document/pdfxchange_portable/PDFXCview.exe
```

I am not sure why I was able to run this executable directly before I uninstalled my old wine and installed the new one. How can I make `$  PDFXCview.exe` work now?

Note:

```
$ wine /home/tim/program_files/document/pdfxchange_portable/PDFXCview.exe
```

will work.

```
$ wine PDFXCview.exe 

wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\PDFXCview.exe"
```

doesn't work. Note that the path of `PDFXCview.exe` is still in `$PATH`

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

> I uninstalled my wine, and installed a higher version of wine by
> compiling source. However when I run an exe executable (whose path is
> in $PATH), it doesn't work as it used to.

As you have obviously seen the following works correctly

```
wine file.exe
```

---

but the following does not

```
# for a file in the current directory
./file.exe              

# for a file that is included your path             
file.exe
```

---

My version of wine is v1.8.3 from debian/jessie-backports and
should be valid back to, at least, v1.6.2 (which is the default in debian/jessie).

You must do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-binfmt
sudo update-binfmts --import /usr/share/binfmts/wine
```

Now you should be able to execute the binary file as shown above,
without having to call it using wine.

The `exe` file must also be marked as executable:

```
chmod a+x file.exe
```

Comment: Just to add an update....the exe file must also be marked as executable for this to work.

Answer (score 8):

Linux has a mechanism that allows plug-ins to be registered so that the kernel calls an interpreter program when instructed to execute a file: [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc). See [How does chroot's use of qemu for cross compile environments work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151010/how-does-chroots-use-of-qemu-for-cross-compile-environments-work/151039#151039) for a more detailed overview.

Your Wine package registered `/usr/bin/wine` as an interpreter for Windows executables as part of its installation script or via a startup script contained in the package. You can do the same for your home-built `wine`. Some distributions have a mechanism where packages can register interpreters which will then be registered into the kernel at boot time, for example `update-binfmts` on Debian and derivatives. Alternatively, an interpreter can be registered into the kernel during startup by [writing to `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt). I recommend that you look at the package you used to have and adapt the method that was working before.

Comment: Thanks. Later I found that I had some remaining files from my old wine, so I apt-get purge the old wine, but that also installed something for the new wine. After that, I can run a Windows executable directly. Not sure why.

Comment: This has nothing to do with binfmt_misc, it has been correctly triggered with `run-detectors`. It's just `run-detectors` has some bug or simply by-design can't detected installed wine program because of those old files. @Tim

Answer (score 0):

#### It should be caused by the conflict with systemd.

Please check the file `/etc/wsl.conf` and see if the `systemd = true` flag was added under `[boot]` settings as shown below. If so, please switch it to false.

[image: Snipaste_2023-01-12_11-45-09]

For more info, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#per-distribution-configuration-options-with-wslconf

Comment: The question is not about wsl (also this one was asked in 2014). Also I don't understand how systemd can cause conflicts to wine. Did you have the same problem and did you solve it by disabling systemd?

Comment: We were having different problems. Maybe you can have a try. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Okay, listen carefully. This is what you do.

**Place this in /usr/bin/pdfxcview.exe**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call up a command;
wine /home/tim/program_files/document/pdfxchange_portable/PDFXCview.exe
```

Then, invoke from Terminal:

```
$ chmod +x /usr/bin/pdfxcview.exe
```

^ Sets executable bit to on.

```
$ pdfxcview.exe
```

[Source Code Differential](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/160159615/wine1.6_1.7.1-actually1.6-0ubuntu1_1%3A1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1.diff.gz)

Isn't Freedom of Software Great? It seems there is commentary about path. If you print your environment by typing "env" you may see your Program Files directory.

Launchpad Librarian is where Ubuntu Developers keep documentation about their work keeping your system up to date and secure.

Comment: thanks. I understand your method. But when i still had my old wine, I didn't do what you suggested. I did `chmod a+x /home/tim/program_files/document/pdfxchange_portable/PDFXCview.exe`, and added `/home/tim/program_files/document/pdfxchange_portable/` to `$PATH` in ~/.bashrc. Then `$ pdfxcview.exe` worked.

Comment: It's a better practice, my friend, to place "wrapper" scripts to your executable files in your /usr/bin/ directory. It keeps things more organized. It's really a matter of personal preference. Within /usr/bin/, these "wrappers" are accessible from any user. However, ~/.bashrc will only be accessible from your own user's environment exports. The "env" command lists environment variables.

Comment: yes, I think it is a universal method. thanks. Not sure why it worked before without your method.

Comment: What version of WINE did you use before..? Perhaps I can investigate the Source code to discover if it dynamically generated a $PATH to your WINE environment. I know that WINE actually creates a File System to not-emulate Windows Executable.

Comment: My old is wine1.6 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1. My new is wine1.6.2 compiled from source.

Comment: [https://launchpadlibrarian.net/160159615/wine1.6_1.7.1-actually1.6-0ubuntu1_1%3A1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1.diff.gz]

There seems to be commentary about paths for executable. Then again, if you print your environment with, "env," you may see a path that Wine added for your Program Files directory. Isn't Freedom of Software great, being able to see a document that can tell you what broke and what not broke in this release?

Comment: in the output of `env`, no path of wine, only path of PDFXCview.exe

Comment: What is   launchpadlibrarian.net used for?